# Bootstrap issue with col-md-12

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am encountering someting really weird.

I have this structure:

```
<div class="row filterRes">
    <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepickerFrom'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control action" placeholder="Från" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepickerTo'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control action" placeholder="Till" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <button class="btn btn-primary  btn-block col-md-12  ">Filtrera</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem:

The last div with class =

```
 col-md-12
```

is taking up the entire row and positioning itself over the two previous ones.

image in firebug:

[image]

I cant focus the two inputs because of this and I don't really understand it. 
If I set this on the last div:

```
col-xs-6 col-sm-12 col-md-12
```

the issue dissapears but the question remeains.
When I add the class

```
 row
```

I get the same result

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't see the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/s2zwckgy/1/ But I guess you should wrap it in another `row` since a row should contain a max of 12 cols (i believe)

Comment: Cannot reproducce- http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/GZydeP ...but without knowing what any ***extra*** CSS is doing (such as the `filterRes` class`0 we can't help diagnose.

Comment: Some bootstrap tips (I'm not saying you have done them wrong ;-] ): 
(1) Never use rows and cols on the same element, they should be alternating.
(2) the lowst column is enought `col-xs-12` will do `col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12` as well, a different case would be `col-xs-12 col-md-6` which is necessary. 
(3) Always include `col-xs-12` even if the element is supposed to be full width, this is to prevent floating issues
(4) `.form-group` acts as a `.row` be sure to use columns inside as well

Comment: fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8mfe3f3a/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have 2 rows instead of 1. A row is designed to have 12 divisions of space. You are filling 12 and thus breaking the functionality. Here's a [working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/8xgnkpBUDX08QP6CHSoc?p=preview)

**HTML**

```
 <div class="row filterRes">
    <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepickerFrom'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control action" placeholder="Från" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepickerTo'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control action" placeholder="Till" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div></div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <button class="btn btn-primary  btn-block col-md-12  ">Filtrera</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

----------- EDIT -----------------

After having the plunk example, I saw that it had to do with relative positioning of the columns. Fixed plunkr: https://jsfiddle.net/8mfe3f3a/1/

Comment: It was per my understanding that when I fill the 12 spaces thats when i fill one row. I add another 12 to fill the next row inside of a row. 
My reasnoning was have one row with two rows inside of it

Comment: @Ra3IDeN Correct...rows wrap if the content exceeds 12 columns

Comment: @Ra3IDeN You are correct... Do you have a defined height on the "filterRes" class?

Comment: @DanielHigueras no I don't. Your answer does solve my problem but I don't understand why this is even happening. I tried not including my own css file and just used the bootstrap.css and I still have this issue

Comment: @Ra3IDeN Create a plunkr reproducing the problem so it's easier to debug. Without that, all we can do is give ideas of what might be happening. Who knows, you might fix the issue yourself creating the plunkr...

Comment: @Ra3IDeN I see it working correctly on your jsfiddle

Comment: Then it must be a browser issue or something. For me it is not working and I am using chrome version 49.0.2623.110. EDIT: I just updated to 49.0.2623.112 m and i still cant focus the inputs

Comment: @Ra3IDeN Working now: https://jsfiddle.net/8mfe3f3a/1/ It's got to do with `position: relative` on the columns.

Comment: It works in the fiddle but in my project it remains the same. I will accept this since I don't want to waste more time but I am curious to why this is happening

Answer (score 2):

### Adding a row:

I might be wrong but this might be a problem:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <button class="btn btn-primary  btn-block col-md-12  ">Filtrera</button>
</div>
```

change it to this, by adding a row:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
        <button class="btn btn-primary  btn-block col-md-12  ">Filtrera</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

each set of columns needs to be wrapped by a row, since rows clear the floating.

---

### Removing the btn column

on the other hand your button does not need 12 columns, btn-block aready does that for you

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Filtrera</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a div with class Row

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <button class="btn btn-primary  btn-block col-md-12  ">Filtrera</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```